# Github Actions Python Unit Test -> Missing Module

Tags: python, unit-testing, github, github-actions

I have a python project with working code in a src module and unit tests in another module.  When I run the unit test using Visual Studio code on my local workstation, the tests run fine.  However, when I check the code into GitHib and use a GitHub action, the unit test cannot find the src directory with the needed modules.  I have tried different configurations on the .yml file but nothing has worked so far.

Here is the .yml

```
jobs:
  on_build_actions:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
        working-directory: src
      - name: Run Tests
        run: python -m unittest test_hypedsearch
        working-directory: test
```

Here is the error

> Run python -m unittest test_hypedsearch E
> ====================================================================== ERROR: test_hypedsearch (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_hypedsearch Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in
> loadTestsFromName
> module = **import**(module_name)   File "/home/runner/work/hypedsearch/hypedsearch/test/test_hypedsearch.py",
> line 5, in 
> from src import runner, utils, database, objects ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

and here is the top of the unit test code that is throwing the error:

```
import sys, os.path  
import unittest
src_path = (os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')) + '/src/')
sys.path.append(src_path)
from src import runner, utils, database, objects
```

Do I need to add a different reference on github to point to the src folder?  Here is the directory outline:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made it work on a similar repository using the following workflow implementation (adapted to your context):

```
jobs:
  on_build_actions:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
      - name: Run Tests    
        run: python -m unittest test/test_hypedsearch.py
```

*I don't know the reason, but I couldn't make it work using the `working-directory` variable as well. So this is a possible workaround...*

Here is the successful workflow run: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/hypedsearch/runs/3032440691?check_suite_focus=true

And here is the repository I used to test if you want to check: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/hypedsearch

*Note: I don't know if this repo is related to yours, but at least it had a similar structure.*

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  Can you fork the repo that we are working on?  https://github.com/ryanlayerlab/hypedsearch.  That other one is an old one that we migrated over to the lab

Comment: I did add cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE line but that did not help...

Comment: Hi! I forked this repo and made the workflow worked [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/hypedsearch/runs/3036075521?check_suite_focus=true) using the [same implementation](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/hypedsearch/blob/main/.github/workflows/cicd.yml) I shared above (I just had to create the `requirements.txt` file as it was missing). Do you want me to open a Merge Request to the repository?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the way to get it to work on GitHub was to remove the reference to the "src" folder:

```
import runner, utils, database, objects
```

Now the challenge is to get that line working in VSCode #sigh